# Android transparent ActionBar

Tags: android, android-theme

For some reason the settings below don't result in the transparent action bar that I am trying for.

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html), this is all that is required. Am I missing something?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".ArtistTopSongsActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentActionBar"
    android:parentActivityName=".ArtistSearchActivity">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".ArtistSearchActivity" />
</activity>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TransparentActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/transparentActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/transparentActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="transparentActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that to in addition to what I had above in the transparent theme, I also had to include the `windowActionBarOverlay` style item, as referenced [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html)

```
<style name="AppTheme.TransparentActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/transparentActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/transparentActionBar</item>

    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```